# Find next value from List of tuples in C#

Tags: c#, list, tuples

So this is out of my acknowledge, maybe some of you can help me.

I have a list with 2 columns. myList, as you can see in the example, will be short and has the first column sorted.

```
private List<(double,double)> myList = new List<(double column1, double column2)> {
    (6,80),
    (8,107),
    (10,134),
    (12,160),
    (16,214),
    (20,267),
    (25,334),
    (32,427),
    (40,534)
};
```

What I need to do is, given a number, let's say 24. Search the next closest value from the list of tuples and return the correct tuple. So it should return (25,334).

If the target is 21, the desired result is `(25,334)`.

My first approach was using lists as I might Add some values in the future. But if you know any kind of struct that adjusts better to this kind of usage, be free to propose.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say "next closest" do you mean that if you were looking for, say, `21` in that example, you would also return `25` because that's the next value - and NOT `20` because (although it's closer in value to the target) it's a preceding value, not a following value ?

Comment: You haven't described any approach yet. A list is just the container. What you posted is a *sorted* list though, which allows using binary search to find the previous and next item for any given number. If the data is already sorted, an array or list is enough. If you load all the data at once, it's cheaper to sort it after insertion, so an array or List is still better. If the data comes little by little while a program is running, a SortedList<int,int> may or may *not* be better.

Comment: Exactly @MatthewWatson, 20 would be not useful. I would return 25.

Comment: What if you search for `23`, which is closest?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I considered saving this data into an array as well. But I don't know which object is cheaper to handle as to search through its items as to add and modify values.

Comment: A list *is* an array. Internally items are stored in a T[] array

Comment: @Jodrell 25 would be

Comment: What are the *actual* requirements? It matters. Real life performance is far more than `O(N)` - CPU caching means that arrays are often faster than linked lists. For a small number of objects, it may be faster to use `.MinBy(item => Math.Abs(item.Item1 - valueToFind));` than sorting and searching.

Comment: `20 would be not useful. I would return 25` in that case you want the *next* item, not the closest. That's far cheaper

Comment: something like `myList.First(p => p.column1 > x )`

Answer (score 1):

If the list is sorted, you can find this element with

```cs
var (x, y) = myList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Item1 >= 24);
```

If no such element is found, then `x` will be `0` and otherwise the required value (`x = 25` in this example and `y = 334`).

Comment: This method is not correct. For example, 31return  25...

Comment: no, 31 returns 32. The OP wants the value that is equal or the next larger one. E.g., according to the comments, for 21 the says 20 would not be useful and he wants 25.

Answer (score 0):

find the closest value from the list:

```
 var result=myList.OrderBy(item => Math.Abs(number - item.Item1)).First();
```

find the next closest value from the list:

```
var result = myList.First(item => item.Item1-number>=0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that your list of tuples is sorted, you can use [binary search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=net-7.0) to find the index of the item matching or following the target. This has `O(Log(N))` complexity, so it's quite efficient:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            List<(double, double)> myList = new List<(double column1, double column2)> {
                (6,80),
                (8,107),
                (10,134),
                (12,160),
                (16,214),
                (20,267),
                (25,334),
                (32,427),
                (40,534)
            };

            double target = 24;

            int index = myList.BinarySearch(
                (target, 0), 
                Comparer<(double, double)>.Create(
                    (lhs, rhs) => lhs.Item1.CompareTo(rhs.Item1)) );

            if (index < 0)
                index = ~index;

            if (index < myList.Count)
                Console.WriteLine($"Found at index {index}, value = {myList[index]}");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Not found");
        }
    }
}
```

[Try it on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CBwdwv)

One bit of fiddlyness is the way that the index is returned by `BinarySearch()` if the item is not found. It will be negative in that event, and you have to take the bitwise not to get the index of the next value. Don't blame me for this. ;)

Another bit of fiddlyness is that you are searching only for the first item in the tuple, so the second is effectively ignored.

Finally, if the item is not found the index will be one beyond the end of the list, so you must account for that too.

Answer (score 0):

One of you answered my question and then deleted the post. I'm not the author of the solution!

```
double target = 21;
var closest = myList.MinBy(item => Math.Abs(item.Item1 - target));
double resultValue = closest.Item2;
```

The result value is 334.

This is what I wanted to do and in just one line. Beautiful

Thanks!

Comment: `The result value is 334.` [No it isn't - it's 267](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fG2DuD), which is not what you wanted.

Comment: You're right @MatthewWatson